# How to add Microsecond and Nanoseconds to DatetTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to add microseconds and nanoseconds to a `DateTime`.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    dateTime  = dateTime.AddMilliseconds(0.1);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd,HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));          
}
```

I can't see any difference in my `dateTime`.
Is this the right way to do that?

Comment: Please see my update, this still the same.

Comment: Looking at the reference source for `AddMilliseconds`, it appears that the code rounds the value to the nearest integer, so even though it takes a double, you cannot add a microsecond in that fashion. (By the way, a microsecond is not 0.1 ms, it is 0.001ms).  In order to accomplish what you want, use the `AddTicks` method:  `dateTime = dateTime.AddTicks(10);`

Comment: I vote for reopen (but agree to close vote for CodeCaster based on the first revision) since the [last revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41919876/revisions) of the question is not _exactly_ the duplicate of the relevant question. If you disagree, please free to ping me or vote to re-close again. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From [`DateTime.AddMilliseconds` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds);

> Parameters
>
> `value`
>
> Type: System.Double
>
> A number of whole and fractional milliseconds. The value parameter can be negative or positive. **Note that this value is rounded to the
>   nearest integer.**

and also you can see it's [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,379) as:

```
public DateTime AddMilliseconds(double value)
{
    return Add(value, 1);
}
```

and called this [`Add` method reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,346);

```
private DateTime Add(double value, int scale)
{
    long millis = (long)(value * scale + (value >= 0? 0.5: -0.5));
    ...
    ...
}
```

for `value = 0.1` and `scale = 1`, it will be

```
long millis = (long)(0.6);
```

and this `(long)(0.6)` returns `0` because [Explicit Numeric Conversions Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) says;

> When you convert from a double or float value to an integral type, **the
>   value is truncated**

So, actually, you are *not* adding anything to that DateTime instance and you get the same results for all iterations. I would work with integers when you deal with `AddXXX` methods of the DateTime to preventing getting confuse.

Since 1 millisecond is 10000 tics, what you do is *mathematically* equal to;

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    dateTime  = dateTime.AddTicks(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd,HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));          
}
```